# s/360 assembly: how to implement a call stack

Tags: assembly, mainframe, callstack, zos, reentrancy

I would like to write a function (in hlasm) which calls itself and other functions.

On a x86 or z80 (and probably others) you would do just call function and at the end of it a ret. The processor will then store and retrieve the return address.

The instruction set has the following instruction:

```
BAL reg,func
```

...which stores the return address in reg, then at the end you can do `BR reg`to jump to that return address. Another problem though is that there are apparently no push/pop instructions.

Comment: You want to call yourself recursively? Do you use the word "function" in a meaningful sense, in that it will originally be called by something which treats it as a function? Same with the functions you say you want to call, Do you meaningfully want them to be functions, or just bits of code you happen to call in a completely normal way? Do you want to implement a "stack" just for fun, or do you just think it must be there somewhere because you are used to them elsewhere? If you are a beginner with z/ARCH ASM, a stack is asking a lot for little apparent purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In System/360 and successor operating systems, the infrastructure to do this is a part of what is called **reentrant** programming. The basic concept is that the storage for the save area pointed to by R13 is obtained from the operating system (think malloc in C). The system macro calls to obtain storage are used at the very beginning of your program. Likewise, the system macro calls to return the storage to the operating system are coded at the exit of your program

You haven't mentioned which operating system you are using. I am going to make the following assumptions for this example code:

- this is for z/OS or a predecessor operating system (OS/390, MVS, OS/VSn, OS/360);
- the code is AMODE 24 or 31, in non-access-register mode (introducing AMODE 64 or ARs changes save area formats);
- this is not running in a Language Environment (LE) situation;
- register equates in the form Rn have been defined;
- and I have not counted columns for the comments (so they may wander into 72).

This skeletal routine is reentrant, and because of that it can also be used recursively, as you mentioned (with caveats that bad code reinvoking itself will eventually lead to out-of-storage abends). The code requires a base register, but I suggest using the modern coding method called "baseless", where the code itself does not use a base register, as it uses the relative & immediate instructions for branches. (You always need a base register for data.)

```
WORKAREA  DSECT ,                    Reentrant work area (like C stack)
          DS    18F                  Save area
FIELD1    DS    F                    Some variable
FIELD2    DS    F                    Another variable
WORKLEN   EQU   *-WORKAREA           Length of reentrant work area

SUBRTN1   RSECT ,                    HLASM will perform reentrant checking
          STM   R14,R12,12(R13)      Save registers at entry
          LR    R12,R15              Set code base register
          USING SUBRTN1,R12          Establish code addressability
          LGHI  R0,WORKLEN           Get length of reentrant work area
          STORAGE OBTAIN,            Obtain reentrant work area                  X
                LENGTH=(0)           ..Length is in R0
          ST    R1,8(,R13)           Forward chain in prev save area
          ST    R13,4(,R1)           Backward chain in next save area
          L     R14,20(,R13)         Get R1 at entry (parameters)          
          LR    R13,R1               Set up new save area/reentrant workarea
          USING WORKAREA,R13         Establish work area addressability
          LM    R2,R3,0(R14)         Get addresses of parameters
          STM   R2,R3,FIELD1         Save parameter addresses for later
…
***    Logic goes here
…
          LR    R1,R13               Address to be released
          L     R13,4(,R13)          Address of prior save area
          LGHI  R0,WORKLEN           Length of storage to release 
          STORAGE RELEASE,           Release reentrant work area                 X
                ADDRESS=(1),         ..Address in R1                             X
                LENGTH=(0)           ..Length in R0
          LM    R14,R12,12(R13)      Restore registers
          OI    15(R13),X'01'        This bit on means this save area is inactive
          BR    R14                  Return to caller
```

This is a very basic example, and introduces some advanced assembler concepts, like a DSECT (dummy section), which describes an area without actually allocating storage in the program. RSECT is a way for the assembler to reinforce reentrancy, by issuing warnings if the program tries to modify itself. (There's also an assembler option, RENT, but that does it for the entire source; RSECT is just for that section.)

The key thing to remember about this example is that you have two base registers, one addressing code, one addressing data. This has parallels with the early x86 architecture, with the code segment and data segment. In this case, the data segment also is used as the stack segment.

Reentrant programs is an essential part of systems-level z/Architecture programming, as it's practically required for multitasking environments. It's an important technique to understand if one will code applications (in a general sense) beyond typical batch programs.

If you are in an LE environment (COBOL, PL/I, C/C++, or assembler main program), you should use the LE-supplied CEEENTRY and CEETERM macros. LE-compiler-generated programs are generally reentrant (even COBOL with the NORENT option). Make sure you code MAIN=NO on the CEEENTRY macro, otherwise all sorts of performance problems and possible logic errors occur. The LE stack mechanism is an advanced version of the technique that I demonstrated above, most notably allocating a large area dedicated to stack usage, so that subsequent calls don't have the overhead of calling the operating system to obtain storage.

If you are working in a z/VSE or z/VM environment, or the non-IBM BS2000/OSD environment, I can modify the above example.

Please comment with questions, and I will update this example for additional clarity.

Comment: The `CEEENTRY` and `CEETERM` macros are worthy of consideration.  They do entail using the Language Environment (LE) compatible versions of some commonly used system macros, such as `CEEGTST` instead of `STORAGE`.  There's a section in the LE manuals in the Knowledge Center about this.

Comment: Good point, but I didn't want to over-complicate things too much in this example. I will add it if requested by the OP. I've written a set of macros that deal with all AMODE combinations, LE yay or nay, creating a stack architecture if desired, and checks if invoked by a Metal C-generated assembler program. I really should submit them to the CBT, but there are the 'round tuit' issues.

Comment: There's also the `BAKR` and `PR` instructions, but I've never used them.

Comment: `BAKR`/`PC`/`PT`/`PR` implement a real register/PSW (and a couple of other minor system-type things) linkage stack that exists in the architecture (the linkage stack is addressed by a control register). The only users these days pretty much are program calls. One problem was that for many years, `BAKR`/`PR` messed with RTM and ESTAEs; strange things would happen, and people wouldn't use them if they couldn't debug. It's not a problem any more, but inertia is pretty powerful (I have stories regarding R&I branches). That macro set of mine also has `BAKR`/`PR` support, if desired.

Comment: With BS2000 one would use COLUMBUS runtime/macros anyway.

Comment: I would love to have a play account on a BS2000/OSD system. I miss it. It’s fun!

Answer (score 4):

Here are a few thoughts beyond what's been posted already.

First, any sophisticated assembler programmer will have thought about subroutine linkages and will have built up preferences over the years. In addition to something that "works", you want something that's efficient, simple and easy to debug. There are three parts to a solution:

1. How and where you save/restore status.
2. What you do to locate and call your subroutines and get results from them.
3. What you need to do inside the called subroutine.

### SAVING STATUS

Saving status is a complex issue. The example above from "zarchasmpgmr" shows the classic approach with chained save areas, and if you are calling things you don't control, you should be familiar with how this works. Sometimes, this isn't the best approach, however, since the "STORAGE OBTAIN" that you see in the example is a system service that's not "free" in terms of execution efficiency. In other words, if you call lots of subroutines and they each acquire/free work areas, you'll find that your assembler language routine is much slower than, say, the same thing written in C.

My personal preference is to use a save area "stack" with multiple entries one after the next. When you call a subroutine, the subroutine saves its registers on the stack and increments the stack pointer (R13) to the next frame - fast, simple and no need for system services. It's even easy to debug since the entire call stack is generally contiguous.

So what's in a stack "frame"? At very least, you need the non-parameter registers (R2-R12), although for debugging I often like to save R0-R15. Also for debugging, I like to save something like a timestamp and maybe even the name of the subroutine that "owns" the stack frame.

Turns out if you just store a timestamp and all sixteen registers, what you need fits in about 80 bytes - I might declare it this way:

```
WORKAREA DSECT , 
STACK    DS    10CL80         A 10-entry subroutine save stack 
         DS    80X'FF'        End of stack marker
```

You can of course include all sorts of extra things in your stack frames. For instance, instead of a timestamp, you might want the name of the subroutine or something like that.

At the start of the program, this is all setup once, and then R13 is used to point to the stack...as routines are called, R13 floats up and down the stack such that it's always pointing to the first usable frame.

As a side note, since R13 actually points to an area any called program can use to save its registers into, this type of stack frame can also be used when calling routines that expect standard OS-style linkage conventions. In this case, what you'd see in the stack frame would be like the standard linkage above, but for the most part, you don't need to worry about calling some unknown service that's not going to like your private stack frame idea.

Only drawback of this approach is that it's not terrific for deep recursion since you usually allocate a fixed number of stack frames. If you have deep recursion, you need to check for the end of the stack and have some strategy for growing the stack should the initial amount not be adequate.

I'll note that you can use the system linkage stack in much the same way...you'd issue the "BRANCH AND STACK" (BAKR) instruction, and under the covers, the hardware is maintaining something pretty similar to what I laid out above. Only thing is that BAKR saves lots more status information, so it's somewhat slower than what I describe.

### CALLING SUBROUTINES

Pretty much no matter how you setup status saving, the trick is to locate and branch to the subroutine. As part of this, you want to think about any parameters you're passing to the called routine - normally R1 would contain (or point to) whatever parameters you want, though sometimes R0 can be useful as well, especially if the routine is something that you control.

There are a few ways to code the actual call sequence, but the traditional approach is to call the subroutine with R14 containing the target subroutine address and R15 containing the return address.

There's a difference between small, casual programs and what you might have to do in a larger application. You used an example of BAL Rx,subroutine - this works, but the subroutine that you're calling needs to be addressable on whatever base register you have going, and it also has to be part of the same compilation unit (that is, the label "subroutine" in BAL Rx,subroutine needs to be in the same source file).

If you're calling subroutines in a larger app, or if you want to assemble your subroutines separately, creating maybe a library of object modules with a member for each subroutine, you can't use BAL. Again, there are lots of solutions here, but my preference is to use either an A- or V-type literal to load the address of the subroutine into R15, and then BALR instead of BAL:

```
* 
* Call the subroutine
*
       LA   R1,some_parameter       R1  -> subroutine parameter
       L    R15,=A(Subrtn)          R15 -> subroutine address
       BALR R14,R15                 Call the subroutine
```

With this approach, the subroutine can be anywhere...all that needs to be within the base register is the literal pool (and LTORG lets you put is wherever you like). If you want subroutines in completely different modules, all you need to do is change the =A() to =V().

If you want to use the system provided linkage stack, it's not very different - BAKR 0,R15 is used instead of the BALR instruction.

When the subroutine completes, it returns control to the instruction immediately following the BALR. Typically, the results of the subroutine are returned in R15, though sometimes R0/R1 are used as well. For instance, if I had a subroutine that obtained storage for something, I might use R15 to indicate whether it succeeded or not (sort of like ERRNO), and if R15 = 0, R0 would be set to the length and R1 set to the address of the object.

Point is, you can use the parameter registers in creative ways, and often it's much more efficient to return results in a few registers, versus storing the results in memory somewhere and returning the address of a result area.

### INSIDE THE CALLED ROUTINE

Okay, let's say you used BALR R14,R15 to get to the subroutine. This gives us:

- R0/R1 have whatever parameters were passed to the subroutine
- R13 contains the address of an available stack frame
- R14 has the return address back to the caller
- R15 has the address of the subroutine itself

What you want to do is save the registers on the stack so that you'll be able to restore them properly when you return to the caller. If you're coding a big application with base register issues and so forth, you'll also need to handle a few cases around local addressability inside the subroutine. Putting it together, you tend to get code that's sort of like this:

```
*
* Called subroutine
*
           PUSH  USING           Guarantees no "stale" USINGs here
           DROP  , 
Subrtn     CSECT ,               Allows subroutines in a different object      
           STCK  0(R13)          Saves the timestamp in the stack 
           STM   R0,R15,8(R13)   Save the caller's registers
           LA    R13,80(R13)     R13 -> next stack frame
           LR    Rx,R15          Setup a local base register
           USING Subrtn,Rx
           . . .        
           . . .                 (Subroutine does it's work here)
           . . .
SubExit    EQU   *               
*
* Return to the caller here R0/R1 have our result, R15 = return code
*
           SLR   R15,R15         (we'll assume a good return code)
           SHI   R13,80          Back up to prior stack frame
           LM    R2,R14,16(R13)  Re-load caller's R2/R14
           BR    R14             Return to the caller 
           LTORG ,               Force subroutine literal pool here
```

If you needed to handle large-scale recursion, you'd add a few instructions to check for the end of the stack frame (a stack frame starting with X'FF') and then have whatever strategy you like for expanding the stack.

If you used BRANCH AND STACK, the return is a little simpler - just comes down to a PROGRAM RETURN instruction that pops the stack frame and returns to wherever the stack frame was created.

No matter what you do, program entry/exit and subroutine linkages are wonderful things to write as assembler macros and reuse over and over in all your applications. In my personal bag of tricks, you'd find a lot of these things so that when I need to write something new, I have all this nuts and bolts stuff worked out already.

One poster pointed out the LE assembler macros (CEESTART etc), and they absolutely do a lot of what I'm describing, at a price of some additional complexity but with the added value that you can freely call LE runtime functions as though they were your own subroutines. The point is to spend as little time worrying about the trivia as possible, and as much time as possible worrying about the real task at hand.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a subroutine in your own programs, then BAS (Branch and Save)/BR is the standard. If the subroutine then calls another subroutine, you can save the caller's address and then restore it later:

```
          <some code>
          BAS R10,SUBRTN1        .Branch to subroutine
          <some mode code>
          .
          .
          .
*
SUBRTN1   DS  0H
          ST  R10,R10SAVE         .Save Return address
          BAS R10,SUBRTN2         .Call subroutine 2
          L   R10,R10SAVE         .Restore return address
          BR  R10                 .and return
*
SUBRTN2   DS  0H
          <some code>
          BR  R10                 .Return to caller
```

However, this is for 'internal' subroutines and you have to be careful that the subroutine does not overwrite registers used by the main program.

If that is a risk, then you might want to use the standard linkage conventions where one program calls another and the calling program provides a save area for the called program to save the callers registers etc.

Comment: Hi Steve, sofar I had that figured out already :-) The problem is that in my cases it is possible that e.g. SUBRTN1 calls SUBRTN1 and then again. So I need some kind of stack to remember all the return addresses.

Comment: @FolkertvanHeusden OK - so you want to be able to use recursion? In that case I think you are going to have to make your subroutine(s) separate re-entrant load modules and use standard z/Os assemble register save/restore processing to 18F of storage obtained via STORAGE OBTAIN. I must admit to not have done any recursive assembler though, but I might give it a try to see how to do it.

Comment: Are you trying to come up with some generic code that allows for calling subroutines (even themselves)  from anywhere without worrying about register save/restore, or do you have a particular situation that you are trying to code for?

Comment: I've you want to use recursion you will either have to write a reasonably sophisticated linkage model along the lines of how Metal/C works with a NAB pointer or keep it simple and use a simple array and pass a element to the recursive routine which includes storage for the save area. address.

Comment: @DavidCrayford - This would be simpler if you limited yourself to a pre-defined maximum recursion depth, yes?

Comment: @SteveIves Absolutely! With Metal/C NAB the stack has no overflow checks so you have to be very careful. But you can roll your own prolog macros and add stack overflow checks. Of course, this comes with a cost which is why XPLINK C/C++ ditched it and used guard pages with an ESTAE to trigger stack expansion.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the usual convention on S/360 (at least under Z/OS) is complicated and doesn't use a standard callstack.

But just for fun, I'll answer the question naively for RISCs in general (and presumably possible on S/360 hardware, whether or not it's even viable under Z/OS or Linux S/390).

---

On x86, `push reg` is equivalent to `sub rsp,8` / `mov [rsp], reg`  (but without setting flags).  On an ISA like MIPS or most other RISCs, including S/360, you can simply emulate push and pop using 2 instructions.

The callstack isn't magical; push and pop are just peephole optimizations to *efficiently* do common operation of store or load and decrementing or incrementing a pointer.

You could in theory choose any register to use as your stack pointer, if you were inventing a new calling convention / ABI, unless there are any implicit uses of a certain register by hardware (e.g. for interrupt handlers).

---

A branch-and-link / indirect-branch is again RISC-like, and is how all RISCs work (MIPS, PowerPC, ARM, etc.)  In non-leaf functions, simple treat the link register like any other call-preserved register and save/restore it on the stack.

E.g. on function entry, reserve enough space for locals and save slots with one `sub`, then `st` or `stm` the registers you want to save.  Before returning, reload any necessary registers, including the link register, then you can return normally.

Look at GCC or clang output for an ISA like MIPS which also has no specific stack instructions (and no async use of the stack even for interrupt handlers) so implementing a callstack is 100% a software convention, not required by the ISA.